# Dynamically determine enum type in Rust

Tags: rust

I am reading the docs on [strum crate](https://docs.rs/strum/0.15.0/strum/). It is mostly about getting the enum VARIANTs out from a string. Is it possible to get the enum type from a string. Specifically, is the following possible?

```rust
extern crate strum;
extern crate strum_macros;
use strum_macros::{Display, EnumIter}; 

#[derive(??, EnumIter, Debug)]
enum TypeA { Variant1, Variant2 }

fn main() {
  for variant in magic_fn("TypeA")::iter() {
    println!("{:?}", variant);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't really think of a way to do this without either reflection or a global registry of types. The latter isn't impossible, but would require significantly more infrastructure. Not answering because I'm not 100% sure it's impossible, but I *strongly* suspect it is.